# Global Average Pooling for Multi-label Segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision

From my understanding, GAP models the image-level classification information. Does it make any sense to use GAP for predicting a segmentation mask when you have more than 1 class? Won't GAP only favour the most frequently occurring class and defeat the purpose of multi-class segmentation? If it does make sense to use GAP, how would you go about doing so?